# How can I look up data in my code without lots of if/elif/elif/... conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a personal project of mine and right now my program is a ton of if-statements based off dictionaries I made holding each seasons episode number (different seasons have different number of episodes) and title. I get the desired results, however I am stuck in trying to find a more advanced method such as using a function, list comprehension or objects to display it more elegantly and with less lines of code.

I've been trying to figure out how to use one of these other methods via googling and tutorials but I can't wrap my head around how I can apply it to my specific program to get the results without all of these individual if-statements.

```
epTitles1 = {"1" : "The Gang Gets Racist",
             "2" : "Charlie Wants an Abortion",
             "3" : "Underage Drinking: A National Concern",
             "4" : "Charlie Has Cancer",
             "5" : "Gun Fever",
             "6" : "The Gang Finds a Dead Guy",
             "7" : "Charlie Got Molested"}

epTitles2 = {"1" :  "Charlie Gets Crippled",
             "2" : "The Gang Goes Jihad",
             "3" :  "Dennis and Dee Go on Welfare",
             "4" : "Mac Bangs Dennis' Mom"  ,
             "5" : "Hundred Dollar Baby"    ,
             "6" : "The Gang Gives Back",
             "7" : "The Gang Exploits a Miracle",
             "8" : "The Gang Runs for Office",
             "9" : "Charlie Goes America All Over Everybody's Ass",
             "10" : "Dennis and Dee Get a New Dad"}


x = int(input("Enter a season between 1 and 13 or 0 for random season: "))

print("You selected season:", x)

if x == 0:
    randomSeason = random.randint(1,13)
    print("Random season:", randomSeason)

    if randomSeason == 1:
        episode = random.randint(1,7)           
        print("Episode:", episode)

        if episode == 1:
            print(epTitles1["1"])
        elif episode == 2:
            print(epTitles1["2"])
        elif episode == 3:
            print(epTitles1["3"])
        elif episode == 4:
            print(epTitles1["4"])
        elif episode == 5:
            print(epTitles1["5"])
        elif episode == 6:
            print(epTitles1["6"])
        elif episode == 7:
            print(epTitles1["7"])

    if randomSeason == 2:
        episode = random.randint(1,10)           
        print("Episode:", episode)

        if episode == 1:
            print(epTitles2["1"])
        elif episode == 2:
            print(epTitles2["2"])
        elif episode == 3:
            print(epTitles2["3"])
        elif episode == 4:
            print(epTitles2["4"])

# same pattern continues for each season (13 seasons)
```

I would just like to learn and understand what kind of method/approach would help condense my code in a more practical way and how to do it.

Comment: Why don't you just directly index with the episode? ``print(epTitles1[str(episode)])``? Why are you titles indexed by strings anyway - you could just use ``print(epTitles1[episode])`` if the titles where in lists.

Comment: It seems to me, the easiest way to condense it would be to alter your dictionaries that were not included with your post. Next best thing would be string formatting.

Comment: You're using the word "dictionary" over and over, but I don't see any actual Python [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping)s in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your data inside a dict of dicts. Outer dict references the seasons, inner dict has the part-number and the title of this part:

```
import random

# see below for a user input safe variant
def get_random_title_of_radnom_season(data):
    season = random.choice(list(data))   # replace with int numeric user input
    nr = random.choice(list(data))       # replace with int numeric user input
    title = data.get(season, {0:"does not exists"}.get(nr,0)    

    return f"Season {season} title {nr} was {title}"


# first index is the season, its value is a dict with partnr, title  
d = {1 : { a: f"Title {a}" for a in range(1,15) },
     2 : { a: f"Title {a}" for a in range(1,10) }, 
     3 : { a: f"Title {a}" for a in range(1,4)  } }

print(get_random_title_of_radnom_season(d))
```

This is how your data looks after expanding the dict comprehensions:

```
{1: {1: 'Title 1',         2: 'Title 2',         3: 'Title 3',
     4: 'Title 4',         5: 'Title 5',         6: 'Title 6',
     7: 'Title 7',         8: 'Title 8',         9: 'Title 9',
     10: 'Title 10',      11: 'Title 11',       12: 'Title 12',
     13: 'Title 13',      14: 'Title 14'},
 2: {1: 'Title 1',         2: 'Title 2',         3: 'Title 3',
     4: 'Title 4',         5: 'Title 5',         6: 'Title 6',
     7: 'Title 7',         8: 'Title 8',         9: 'Title 9'},
 3: {1: 'Title 1',         2: 'Title 2',         3: 'Title 3'}}
```

Multiple outputs:

```
Season 3 title 3 was Title 3    
Season 3 title 1 was Title 1    
Season 3 title 2 was Title 2    
Season 2 title 4 was Title 4    
Season 1 title 9 was Title 9
```

You could also look into using [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) if you do not like "naked" dictionaries.

---

To make it user input proof instead of using randoms from the dict:

```
def get_user_title_of_radnom_season(data, season, nr): 
    title = data.get(season, {}).get(nr,False)
    return f"Season {season} title {nr} was {title}" if title else "Does not exist"

print(get_user_title_of_radnom_season(d, 99, 99))
```

Will print `"Does not exist"` for any keys that are not appropriate

Answer (score 0):

You can make your dictionaries this way

```
epTitles1 = {1:"s1ep1", 2:"s1ep2", 3:"s1ep3"}
epTitles1 = {1:"s2ep1", 2:"s2ep2", 3:"s2ep3"}
```

or you can even have a single dictionary of lists ( or list of lists) for all of the seasons

```
epTitles = { 1:["s1ep1", "s1ep2", "s1ep3"], 2:["s2ep1", "s2ep2", "s2ep3"] }
```

Then you can access them this way

```
print("You selected season:", x)
if x == 0:
    randomSeason = random.randint(1,13)
    print("Random season:", randomSeason)

    episode = random.randint(1,7)           
    print("Episode:", epTitles[randomSeason][episode-1])
```

You can also have the episodes ranges for random selection saved in a dict of tuples to minimize the code even more, so the **final code** will be like this

```
epTitles = { 1:["s1ep1", "s1ep2", "s1ep3"], 2:["s2ep1", "s2ep2", "s2ep3"] }
epRanges = { 1:(1,7), 2:(1,10) }

x = int(input("Enter a season between 1 and 13 or 0 for random season: "))
print("You selected season:", x)
if x == 0:
    randomSeason = random.randint(1,13)
    print("Random season:", randomSeason)

    episode = random.randint(epRanges[randomSeason][0], epRanges[randomSeason][1])           
    print("Episode:", epTitles[randomSeason][episode-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions! I was able to drastically shorten it by putting all the episodes in a single dictionary and used tuples as the keys. Then I was able to filter out the keys based on the users input and print out the season and episode's title